# Sharing a state across components in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a few custom components in my React app that fetch data from an outside API to display information in my app.

I am trying to figure out the best way to pass a loading state from my child component to the parent component.

This is my App.js:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Loader show={loading} />
      <Navbar />
      <Main />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my Main.js:

```
const Main = () => {

    const [ images, setImages ] = useState([]);
    const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {

        const getFeed = async () => {
            
            setLoading(true);
            const response = await fetch(`https://localhost/api/feed`);
            const data = await response.json();

            const results = data.data.results;
            setImages(results);
            setLoading(false);
        }

        getFeed();

    }, []);

    

        return (
                <Grid container spacing={2} className="media">
                    {
                        images.map((image, index) => {
                            return (
                                <Grid container item xs={6} sm={3} md={2}>
                                    <ImageItem key={ `image_${ index }` } details={ image } />
                                </Grid>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </Grid>
        );
}

export default Main;
```

How can I get the `loading` state from my `Main` component in my `App` component?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

App. js

- you should create the `loading` state in the App.js

```
const App = () => {
const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Loader show={loading} />
      <Navbar />
      <Main setLoading={setLoading} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Main.js

- pass the `setLoading` as a props to the Main component and receive it.

```
const Main = ({setLoading} ) => {
    const [ images, setImages ] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {

        const getFeed = async () => {
            
            setLoading(true);
            const response = await fetch(`https://localhost/api/feed`);
            const data = await response.json();

            const results = data.data.results;
            setImages(results);
            setLoading(false);
        }

        getFeed();

    }, []);

    

        return (
                <Grid container spacing={2} className="media">
                    {
                        images.map((image, index) => {
                            return (
                                <Grid container item xs={6} sm={3} md={2}>
                                    <ImageItem key={ `image_${ index }` } details={ image } />
                                </Grid>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </Grid>
        );
}

export default Main;
```

That's all

Comment: This worked great. I had to make one change, in the `useEffect` hook I had to declare the  the `setLoading` like this: `useEffect(() => { ... }, [setLoading]);`.

Answer (score 0):

If the Loading component doesn't do anything other than display some loading ui, move it down to the Main component so it has direct access to the loading state.

so you might end up with something like this in your render

```
<>
<Loading show={loading} />
<Grid container spacing={2} className="media">
                    {
                        images.map((image, index) => {
                            return (
                                <Grid container item xs={6} sm={3} md={2}>
                                    <ImageItem key={ `image_${ index }` } details={ image } />
                                </Grid>
                            );
                        })
                    }
</Grid>

</>
```